# Can I get Mountain Lion on a MacBook?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, leopard

I own a [MacBook](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1159#MacBook) which I purchased approximately 6 years ago (I'm not sure exactly what version it is, but I can get that information if needed). It is running OS X Leopard, and I want to install Mountain Lion onto it.

Is this possible? If so, how? If not, what is the most recent OS I can get on the system?

Comment: You need to give the version of MacBook for us to help. Also what does the link for MacBook you gave attempt to show?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not. The system requirements for 10.8 say "MacBook (Late 2008 Aluminum, or Early 2009 or newer)". You'd also need to install 10.6.8 or 10.7 first in order to install Mountain Lion from App Store.

See these Apple KB articles:

- [System requirements for OS X Mountain Lion](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5444)
- [System requirements for OS X Lion and Mac OS X v10.6](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4949)
- [How to identify MacBook models](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1635)

EveryMac.com has a list of maximum OS X versions supported by different Macs:

- http://www.everymac.com/systems/by_capability/maximum-macos-supported.html
- http://www.everymac.com/mac-answers/os-x-lion-faq/macs-compatible-with-os-x-lion-hack-options-for-incompatible-macs.html

Answer (score 1):

Some older MacBooks are supported by [MLPostFactor](http://www.osxhackers.com/Installation.html), although even then they want you to install 10.7 (Lion) first.  Upgrading has enough pitfalls that I would recommend not skipping major OS versions anyway, meaning upgrading to Snow Leopard then Lion then Mountain Lion.

However, if your MacBook is supported by Mountain Lion and you want to risk upgrading in one operation, you can [create a bootable Mountain Lion USB drive](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/07/how-to-create-a-bootable-backup-mountain-lion-install-disk/) and install from that.